# How to like a Feed Post (Image/Status) on Facebook using LikeView on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am using

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeview);
                likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                         URL or a Facebook ID ???,
                        LikeView.ObjectType.?????);
```

how can i like a photo or any post from the home feeds using LikeView

what the Url and ObjectType should be?

ps: the like of a page is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The Like button can be used to like a Facebook Page or any Open Graph object and can be referenced by URL or ID." So you cannot like a post with Likeview. The usual way is using graph api to like post/photo.